# openGL createWindow wont execute till end of application code

Tags: opengl

I have a program which allows the user to pick an image through a dialog box,  and displays the image. A menu is associated with a right click on the image and when the user chooses clustering, the user is prompted to input the minimum distance between clusters at the console.
The display window is created by calling the `viewer()` method, which creates a window and sets the GLUT properties for it.
I wanted to destroy the original window with the loaded image at the time the user was being prompted for an input at the console, since many times, the console window was getting in the way of the image display window.

After the user inputs the value at the console, I wanted the window to get displayed again. But the problem is that though I call the `viewer()` function after reading in the input, the window does not appear again till the next function call `Clustering()` has finished executing. If I didn't destroy the first window and moved my console window away, however I am able to see changes to the image as the clustering algorithm gets executed.

My question is, why is this explicit call to `createWindow` being ignored and the next command being executed. I tried using `glFinish` , but it did not help :-( Can someone offer me a solution?

My pseudocode looks something like this:

```
Clustering()
{
    loop
    {
        image processing code
    }
    display()  ;
}

...

display()
{
    drawing code
    glutSwapBuffers()
}

void viewer() {

   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
   glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);

   win = glutCreateWindow("Image"); 

   glutCreateMenu(menu);
   glutAddMenuEntry("Load Image", 1);
   glutAddMenuEntry("Clustering", 3);
   glutAddMenuEntry("QUIT", 99);
   glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
   glutMouseFunc(mouse);
}

void menu(int id) {

glutSwapBuffers();

switch (id){
    case 1://Open image
                    ...........
        break;  

    case 3://Clustering
        glutDestroyWindow(win);
        cout << "Please enter in the minimum distance between regions - a value between 1 and " << max_distance << ": \n";
        cin >> distance;

        Viewer();
        Clustering();
        break;

    case 99:
        exit(0);
}
glutPostRedisplay();
}

main()
{
    ....
    viewer();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Oh, by the way, I have checked [How to update display in OpenGL during processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509091/how-to-update-display-in-opengl-during-processing) already .

Though the question was very similar, the actual problem is slightly different.

Comment: First, `glutCreateWindow` and `glFinish` has nothing in common. Second, what version of GLUT you are using?

Comment: Have you considered using `glutHideWindow` and `glutShowWindow` for to temporarily hide the window?

Comment: Am using glut3.6 . I meant that I tried calling glFinish() before calling the createWindow() method. Forgive me if I am wrong, but my understanding was that glFinish forces all pending operations to get executed before proceeding.

Comment: Am currently using glHideWindw and glShowWindow() , but again , it seems to have no effect :-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that things work the way you imagine. For example `glutDestroyWindow` also destroys the OpenGL context (this is a limitation of GLUT, not OpenGL, which allows to have a OpenGL context "in limbo" without a window around, just fine). So if you constantly create and destroy windows, you also have to reload all images, textures, etc. inbetween.

Seriously, if you've reched those limits of GLUT, like you did, it's time to abandon GLUT and use a "real" toolkit. Like Qt or wxWidgets or GTK+.

Comment: Thank you all! Looks like I will have to live with the window open and will just have to manually switch focus to it using the mouse. I am stuck with using GLUT (it is for a class project and has to run on any system at school) , but appreciate all the inputs! Thanks again!

Comment: @msnewbie: What operating system is running on the systems in your school?

Comment: Hi datenwolf, most of the computers at my school have Windows 7, and VisualStudio 2010 installed. Thanks! I must add, we were given glut32.dll, glut.h and glut32.lib files to use with the project.The custom glut.h file includes the glut header files under GL/gl.h and GL/glu.h though.

Comment: @msnewbie: Okay that's really not much. If you were aiming for the long shot you could still make direct use of the Win32 API. It's a bit tedious, but may actually better in your case, than behing dragged down by GLUT.